# What is /opt/ros/groovy/setup.sh for in the ~/.bashrc

Tags: ros, ros-groovy, setup.sh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm now transferring from Fuerte to Groovy. I found that after setting up the workspace, I don't need the line "source /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash" in ~/.bashrc . It seems that only "source $HOME/code/ros_groovy/devel/setup.bash" is needed in ~/.bashrc. I can still create and make package, and run a node successfully without "source /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash".

What will happen if I omit this line in the .bashrc?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63700/what-is-/opt/ros/groovy/setup.sh-for-in-the-%7E/.bashrc/) by [Albert K](https://answers.ros.org/users/1569/albert-k/) on ROS Answers with karma: 301 on 2013-05-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I imagine you have `source /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash` somewhere in your other bash file.

If you do, then you should not have to source the file in the .bashrc.

If you don't, however, try omitting it/commenting it out (use a '#' in front of the line). If it doesn't work, then replace it.

I don't know what would happen if you sourced it twice. I'm pretty sure it would not break anything. If I were you, I'd try it. If it doesn't work, reverse it.

Make a copy of your current settings:

```
cp ~/.bashrc ~/.bashrc.old
```

Then modify it. If it breaks stuff, then just do:

```
cp ~/.bashrc.old ~/.bashrc
```

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2013-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Albert K](https://answers.ros.org/users/1569/albert-k/) on 2013-05-28**:
Do you have the similar experience? What will happen if you omit this line on your computer? For my case, I can do the usual works correctly, but I wonder if there might be some problems.

**Comment by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) on 2013-05-28**:
Like Allen mentioned, there is likely a line in $HOME/code/ros_groovy/devel/setup.bash that sources from /opt/ros/groovy See http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment and http://www.ros.org/wiki/catkin/workspaces to understand the environment created with workspace